# Take the average for scores in a given file for Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, average

I'm making a function which takes as input (string, dict) and returns a float. The function accepts as input the text from a file to evaluate and the dictionary for individual words. The function must return the score for the text as a whole. That is, the score is the average of the score of words which appear.

I have a .csv file with a list of words each given a score and std deviation. In the file each line takes the form

```
word{TAB}score{TAB}standard_deviation
```

I'm making the letters all lower case and attempting to take the average of all the scores.

I have this so far but can't figure out with correct method to get the average:

```
def happiness_score(string , dict):
   sum = 0
   for word in string:
      dict = dict()
      if word in dict:
         sum += word
         word = string.lower()
         word,score,std = line.split()
         d[word]=float(score),float(std)
   return sum/len(dict)
```

Comment: Don't use data types as variable names (eg: `dict`). It's very confusing.

Comment: also, that if will always evaluate as false, since you're resetting the dict to an empty value each for each word in string and maybe post your current code. if you're posting examples, identify them precisely (eg: line.split(), dict = dict() etc)

Comment: Theres no way this can even run!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure of the exact mathematical operation you want to perform.
and im not sure if you are able to read the file or not.

but hopefully this will provide some guidance.

```
# to hold your variables
holder_dict = {}

# read the file:
with open("/path/to/file.csv", 'r') as csv_read:
    for line in csv_read.readlines():
        word, score, std = line.split('\t')
        if word in holder_dict.keys():
            holder_dict[word][0] += [float(score)]
            holder_dict[word][1] += [std]
        else:
            holder_dict[word] = [[float(score)],[std]]

# get average score
for word in holder_dict.keys():
    average_score = sum(holder_dict[word][0])/len(holder_dict[word][0])
    print "average score for word: %s is %.3f" % (word, average_score)
```

Comment: You don't need the readlines(). You can just do 'for line in csv'. You can also just use a defaultdict to avoid checking if the word is present in the dictionary before loading it.

Comment: @juniper- yes. but `readlines` if i am not mistaked already does `.strip()` for you. otherwise you would have to take care of `.strip()` in an ugly way. and there are no default dicts as far as i know for lists of lists.

Comment: According to the docs readlines() doesn't do the strip() for you. The default dict can be made like this 'a = defaultdict(lambda:[0,0])'.

Comment: what python are you using? i have 2.6 :(

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from reading your explanation, this may be what you need.

```
def happiness_score(string, score_dict):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for word in string.lower().split():
        if word in score_dict:
            total += score_dict[word]
            count += 1
    return total/count

def compile_score_dict(filename):
    score_dict = {}
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            score_dict[row[0].lower()] = int(row[1])
    return score_dict

score_dict = compile_score_dict('filename.csv')
happiness_score('String to find score', score_dict)
```

Comment: i do not understand your happiness score at all. it is not really doing anything. you are just counting all the scores. nothing to do with score per word in there at all.